# bad character showing up in bash script execution

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a bash script that is getting an accented character appended to some strings that is causing it to fail, and I can't find where or how these characters are getting in there.

Here is some example output:

```
mv: cannot move â/tmp/myapp.zipâ to â/opt/myserver/myapp/deploys/myapp.1.2.21.zipâ: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link â/opt/myserver/myapp/deploys/myapp_beta.zipâ: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat â/opt/myserver/myapp/deploys/myapp_beta.zipâ: No such file or directory
```

the invalid character is the **â**.

The script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=$1

SVN_LOC="https://svn/svn/myserver/"

MYAPP_REPO="myapp.git"
COREJS_REPO="core-js.git"
SPARTAN_REPO="core-spartan.git"

MYAPP_LOCATION="myapp/"
COREJS_LOCATION="corejs/"
SPARTAN_LOCATION="spartan/"

DEPLOY_LOCATION="/tmp/deploy/"
CLEANUP="${DEPLOY_LOCATION}*"

DEPLOY_STORE="/opt/myserver/myapp/deploys/"

DEPLOY_TIME=$(date +%s)

failed ()
{
    rm -rf $CLEANUP
    exit 1
}

mkdir -p $DEPLOY_LOCATION

echo "Retrieving Code from Git Branch ${BRANCH}"

echo "Retrieving myapp code"

mkdir -p "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${MYAPP_LOCATION}"
pushd /opt/myserver/myapp/myapp
git archive $BRANCH | tar -x -C "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${MYAPP_LOCATION}"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failed retrieving code from git ${MYAPP_REPO} repo";
    failed
fi
popd

echo "Checking version numbers"
VERSION=$(php "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${MYAPP_LOCATION}version.php" output)

DEPLOY_PACKAGE="${DEPLOY_STORE}myapp.${VERSION}.zip"

if [ -f $DEPLOY_PACKAGE ]
then
    echo "A deploy with the same version number (${VERSION}) already exists! Please increment version number or manually deal with existing ${DEPLOY_PACKAGE}";
    failed
fi

echo "Retrieving corejs code"

mkdir -p "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${COREJS_LOCATION}"
pushd /opt/myserver/myapp/core-js
git archive $BRANCH | tar -x -C "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${COREJS_LOCATION}"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failed retrieving code from git ${COREJS_REPO} repo";
    failed
fi
popd

echo "Retrieving spartan code"

mkdir -p "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${SPARTAN_LOCATION}"
pushd /opt/myserver/myapp/spartan
git archive $BRANCH | tar -x -C "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${SPARTAN_LOCATION}"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failed retrieving code from git ${SPARTAN_REPO} repo";
    failed
fi
popd

echo "Minifying js and css"

pushd "${DEPLOY_LOCATION}${MYAPP_LOCATION}Server/Deploy/"
php MinifyLyroke.php --deploytime $DEPLOY_TIME
popd

ASSETS_DEPLOY_PACKAGE="${DEPLOY_STORE}myappassets.${VERSION}.zip"
TEMP_ASSETS_ZIP_LOC="/tmp/myappassets.zip"
DEPLOY_ASSETS="${DEPLOY_LOCATION}myapp/Assets/"
ASSETS_DEPLOY_LOCATION="/tmp/assetsdeploy/"
DEPLOYED_ASSETS="${ASSETS_DEPLOY_LOCATION}myappassets_${DEPLOY_TIME}"

mkdir -p $ASSETS_DEPLOY_LOCATION

echo "Packaging assets deploy to ${ASSETS_DEPLOY_PACKAGE}"

mv $DEPLOY_ASSETS $DEPLOYED_ASSETS

pushd $ASSETS_DEPLOY_LOCATION
zip -r ${TEMP_ASSETS_ZIP_LOC} *
popd

mv ${TEMP_ASSETS_ZIP_LOC} ${ASSETS_DEPLOY_PACKAGE}
ln -sfn ${ASSETS_DEPLOY_PACKAGE} "${DEPLOY_STORE}myappassets_beta.zip"
cp "${DEPLOY_STORE}myappassets_beta.zip" "/opt/myserver/myapp/myapp/Server/Deploy/"

rm -rf $DEPLOYED_ASSETS
rm -rf $ASSETS_DEPLOY_LOCATION

echo "Packaging deploy to ${DEPLOY_PACKAGE}"

TEMP_ZIP_LOC="/tmp/myapp.zip"

pushd ${DEPLOY_LOCATION}
zip -r ${TEMP_ZIP_LOC} *
popd

mv "${TEMP_ZIP_LOC}" "${DEPLOY_PACKAGE}"
ln -sfn "${DEPLOY_PACKAGE}" "${DEPLOY_STORE}myapp_beta.zip"
cp "${DEPLOY_STORE}myapp_beta.zip" "/opt/myserver/myapp/myapp/Server/Deploy"

echo "Cleaning up"

rm -rf $CLEANUP
```

can anyone possibly see the issue or suggest a way I can go about finding where the issue is?

Comment: Check your script for *quote* characters.  Looks like you might have undesirable characters instead of `"`.

Comment: Try debugging your script `bash -x ...`.

Comment: By the way, you should always use `#!/bin/bash -e`, especially with scripts that may have dangerous effects. You do NOT want a situation where ``objpath=`get_path ...` `` fails and later causes you to `rm -rf /usr/$objpath` (or something else equally silly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `â` characters are just mangled smart quotes printed from your shell. Your shell is probably outputting UTF-8, but your terminal is reading ISO-8859-1. Note that `â` is the rendering of a UTF-8 encoded smart quote `‘` in ISO-8859-1, with two nonprintable characters following the â. Most modern terminal emulators come with an option to enable UTF-8; see if you can enable that (it will make your life easier).

The problem is in your script, not the funny characters.

Comment: Thanks for this I suspect it is very much something like this. I haven't had any luck finding the offending characters and might just have to rewrite this from scratch

Comment: There are **no** offending characters. That's what I'm trying to point out. Your script is probably using the wrong path or something.

Comment: oh okay make sense it is parsing paths at one stage but not all the strings that have been "infected" are produced that way some are just coded in the script themselves but I follow this line of thought and see what I find

Comment: @Tristan: I don't think you read my answer thoroughly. Your strings aren't "infected"; there **are no weird characters** in your script or in your strings. Just an incorrect encoding setting on your terminal. Try to make sure that the paths you're using actually exist.

Comment: thanks yeah I got that, I guess I don't understand how its effecting things the way it is or how to solve it

Comment: It's **not affecting anything**. Your script is just wrong in some way. **Double check the paths you're using**. One or more of them may not exist. To solve the "funny characters", set your terminal encoding properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the script in another text editor like Notepad++ and see if there are any special characters present.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have done so already and still can't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, type both of these commands.   One or more of the files/directories you are expecting to exist, does not exist.

```
ls /tmp/myapp.zip
ls /opt/myserver/myapp/deploys
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains the problem, thanks @nneonneo. This is what you can do for a quick fix:

A) check your locale settings with:

```
  locale
```

B) before calling your script or in the top of your bash-script try:

```
  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  export LC_ALL=C
```