# syntax error near unexpected token ' - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a written a sample script on my Mac

```
#!/bin/bash
test() {
  echo "Example"
}
test
exit 0
```

and this works fine by displaying     Example

When I run this script on a RedHat machine, it says

> syntax error near unexpected token '

I checked that bash is available using

```
cat /etc/shells

which bash shows /bin/bash
```

Did anyone come across the same issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: hmm I don't know. I can execute this correctly on a Fedora machine.

Comment: Any thing before definition works fine, error is being thrown when control reaches function definition.

Comment: Can you recreate the entire file? Perhaps you have a non-printable in there causing the fault.

Comment: Solved . . Notepad ++ issue . Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @user3155779 Could you close the question, since the actual problem didn't relate to anything asked here (that is, wasn't found in the code as-given byte-for-byte)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the solution was unrelated to the question as asked.

Comment: `test` is an external code in Linux used for testing expression. Example `test -r file` will test if file exists and is readable

Comment: @user3155779 - please post the output of the following commands where "testme.sh" is your problematic script:

`./testme.sh; bash ./testme.sh; od -c ./testme.sh`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It could be a file encoding issue.

I have encountered file type encoding issues when working on files between different operating systems and editors - in my case particularly between Linux and Windows systems.

I suggest checking your file's encoding to make sure it is suitable for the target linux environment. I guess an encoding issue is less likely given you are using a MAC than if you had used a Windows text editor, however I think file encoding is still worth considering.

--- EDIT (Add an actual solution as recommended by @Potatoswatter) 
To demonstrate how file type encoding could be this issue, I copy/pasted your example script into Notepad in Windows (I don't have access to a Mac), then copied it to a linux machine and ran it:

```
jdt@cookielin01:~/windows> sh ./originalfile             
./originalfile: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'/originalfile: line 2: `test() {
```

In this case, Notepad saved the file with carriage returns and linefeeds, causing the error shown above. The `\r` indicates a carriage return (Linux systems terminate lines with linefeeds `\n` only).

On the linux machine, you could test this theory by running the following to strip carriage returns from the file, if they are present:

```
cat originalfile | tr -d "\r" > newfile
```

Then try to run the new file `sh ./newfile` . If this works, the issue was carriage returns as hidden characters.

**Note:** This is not an exact replication of your environment (I don't have access to a Mac), however it seems likely to me that the issue is that an editor, somewhere, saved carriage returns into the file.

--- /EDIT

To elaborate a little, operating systems and editors can have different file encoding defaults. Typically, applications and editors will influence the filetype encoding used, for instance, I think Microsoft Notepad and Notepad++ default to Windows-1252. There may be newline differences to consider too (In Windows environments, a carriage return and linefeed is often used to terminate lines in files, whilst in Linux and OSX, only a Linefeed is usually used).

A similar question and answer that references file encoding is here: [bad character showing up in bash script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081038/bad-character-showing-up-in-bash-script-execution)

Comment: What part of Windows defaults to UTF-16LE? Note that ISO-8859-1 is the same as Windows-1252, which isn't particularly endorsed by ANSI as opposed to Unicode. Also, none of this will make a quote mark show up in an otherwise ASCII file, so -1.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, Windows uses UTF-16 'internally' so its fair to point out that the system does not default everything that way and operating system internals I guess are not relevant to the point I was trying to make, which is that filetype encoding can cause these side-effects. Windows-1252 is a superset of ISO-8859-1, thus they are not the same. The point of my answer is that filetype encoding is often a consideration between operating systems and applications. I have updated the answer, hopefully my point is a little better represented now.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize 1252 had characters instead of control codes for 0x80-0x9F. In that case, there's nothing ANSI about it.

Comment: I suspect the OP's issue was encoding though. I just copied the example into notepad and saved, then copied to linux and sh ./file produces unexpected token errors, including `' type references. To fix I needed to strip the carriage returns. i.e. $ cat originalfile | tr -d "\r" > newfile   then it would execute. Anyway, I agree my answers a little verbose.

Comment: It's not the verboseness, it's the unspecificity ("doing this general kind of thing can cause various types of errors") and factual errors ("ANSI/Windows-1252"). If you reproduced or fixed the problem, you should mention so. It sounds like the shell was complaining about the `^M` carriage return character, not the quote as the OP seemed to indicate.

Comment: Hi @Potatoswatter, I was not able to replicate the OP's environment exactly so leaned towards being non-specific, however I appreciate your feedback regarding structuring answers suitably on SE and will keep it in mind in the future. I also agree the ANSI/Windows-1252 reference is incorrect having looked it up again. I will update the answer again fixing the ANSI/Windows-1252 mis-association and a test the OP could use to confirm whether the carriage return is an issue. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

try something like

```
$ sudo apt-get install dos2unix
$ dos2unix offendingfile
```

Comment: Mac uses Unix line endings. This is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 4):

Easy way to convert `example.sh` file to `UNIX` if you are working in Windows is to use NotePad++ (Edit>EOL Conversion>UNIX/OSX Format)

You can also set the default EOL in notepad++ (Settings>Preferences>New Document/Default Directory>select Unix/OSX under the Format box)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @jdt for your answer.

Following that, and since I keep having this issue with carriage return, I wrote that small script. Only run `carriage_return` and you'll be prompted for the file to "clean".

https://gist.github.com/kartonnade/44e9842ed15cf21a3700

```
alias carriage_return=remove_carriage_return
remove_carriage_return(){

# cygwin throws error like : 
# syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
# due to carriage return
# this function runs the following
# cat originalfile | tr -d "\r" > newfile

read -p "File to clean ? "
file_to_clean=$REPLY
temp_file_to_clean=$file_to_clean'_'

# file to clean => temporary clean file
remove_carriage_return_one='cat '$file_to_clean' | tr -d "\r" > '
remove_carriage_return_one=$remove_carriage_return_one$temp_file_to_clean

# temporary clean file => new clean file
remove_carriage_return_two='cat '$temp_file_to_clean' | tr -d "\r" > '
remove_carriage_return_two=$remove_carriage_return_two$file_to_clean

eval $remove_carriage_return_one
eval $remove_carriage_return_two
# remove temporary clean file 
eval 'rm '$temp_file_to_clean
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895946/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-bash#answer-20929197) is **how to check if it is carriage return issue in Unix like environment** (I tested in MacOS)

1) Using cat

```
cat -e my_file_name
```

If you see the lines ended with `^M$`, then yes, it is the carriage return issue.

2) Find first line with carriage return character

```
grep -r $'\r' Grader.sh | head -1
```

3) Using vim

```
vim my_file_name
```

Then in vim, type

```
:set ff
```

If you see `fileformat=dos`, then the file is from a dos environment which contains a carriage return.

After finding out, you can use the above mentioned methods by other people to correct your file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was working  with armbian linux and Windows .
i was trying to coppy my codes from windows to armbian and when i run it this Error Pops Up. My problem Solved this way :
1- try to Coppy your files from windows using WinSCP . 
2- make sure that your file name does not have () characters