# Bash script syntax error "do"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
for repo in repoA, repoB, repoC;
do
    echo Cloning $repo.
done
```

When I execute this (`sh myscript.sh`) I get the following:

```
myscript.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'yscript.sh: line 2: `for repo in repoA repoB repoC;
```

Ideas?

Comment: Check for Windows-style CR/LF in the file. you could do, `echo myscript.sh | od -c` to peak at the characters. The commas are a problem, too. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/.

Comment: Get rid of the commas!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja - The second line of your output printed `\r` which moved the cursor back to where `m` was and printed `'` thus the weird output. Try running `dos2unix myscript.sh`. This should convert CRLF to `\n`. `file myscript.sh` will tell you what kind of file is myscript.sh. `cat -veT myscript.sh` will print the contents of myscript.sh including non-printable characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax error near unexpected token ' - bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895946/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-bash)

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses two characters at the end of each line: `'\r'` and `'\n'`. Unix just uses `'\n'`. Presumably you're editing this in notepad and running it in cygwin, which is why you're getting this error.

Download the [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) editor, which has an option for unix-style line endings under `Edit / EOL Conversion`.

Answer (score 0):

You're script was probably written on a windows machine and contains DOS newlines **CR LF** instead of Unix ones, **LF**

So you just need to convert the newlines.

You can do that using a variety of tools but my preference is **dos2unix**

To install it on **CentOS, Fedora** or **RHEL** do:

```
sudo yum install dos2unix
```

To install **dos2unix** on **Ubuntu or Debian**:

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
```

Now to actually do the conversion do:

```
dos2unix your_script.sh
```

Then run the script

```
sh your_script.sh
```

Answer (score -4):

You forgot a semicolon:

```
#!/bin/sh
for repo in repoA repoB repoC;
do
    echo Cloning $repo.
done
```

Note that repoA, repoB and repoC are being treated as variables in this context.

Comment: Thanks @d33tah (+1) - but still same error. Any ideas? I think it's interesting that the 2nd line of output has `yscript` instead of `myscript`...

Comment: @IAmYourFaja you've got some non-visible control characters in the file. If you copy/paste the one you typed in your question into a script, it will probably work.

Comment: @d33tah you don't need the semicolon. The line break takes care of it. And the `repoA`, `repoB`, and `repoC` are treated as literals in this context. The value of `repo` is set to each, in turn.

Comment: This is still not working; I copy/pasted the raw text from your answer into my script and got the same output as above in my question. I'm on Windows 7 using Cygwin, could that be the culprit?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja what editor are you using? I believe it's writing the file out in "DOS" format with the CR/LFs. Check for an option to use Linux/Unix style text.