# Why is a shell script giving syntax errors when the same code works elsewhere?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, carriage-return

I have a simple shell script I copied from a working script. It works if I copy-paste it to a terminal:

```
if true
then
  true
fi
```

However, when I run the script with `bash myscript`, I get various syntax errors as if some of the keywords are missing.

- `` myscript: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' ``  , as if `then` isn't there.
- `myscript: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file` , as if `fi` isn't there.
- `` myscript: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r' `` .. what?

Why does this happen in this particular script, but not on my command line or in the script I copied from?

Comment: Consider adding http://www.shellcheck.net/ to your automated testing workflow.

Comment: Is there a Windows machine in the vicinity of the code?  Could there be carriage returns in the non-working version? One of the errors uses ```$'\r'``` which suggests this is the problem.  See [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/) amongst many other relevant questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I fabricated this question and gave a community answer because I'm never able to find a general question for marking as duplicate. For example, the one you suggest is about how to convert a file and it would not be obvious to a poster why that's at all relevant. I've added this one to the bash tag wiki, but if you find a better one I'm happy to switch it.

Comment: It's been asked so many times that it is surprising that you failed to find useful information.  Here are a couple [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895946/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-bash), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere)

Comment: @ThomasDickey If you update the bash tag wiki with any question you'd think make a better, general, canonical FAQ for deduping syntax errors due to CR, I'll be absolutely delighted to delete this question! (Finding good ones are tricky, as evidenced by your #2 being this very post.)

Comment: Sorry for the poor example.  Here are a few more: [1](http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/shellProgramming.html), [2](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-213617/), [3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304999/not-able-to-execute-a-sh-file-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter).  "bad interpreter" seems to find the most comments (and answers).  The issue's been around (and well-known) for 10-15 years.  So a *good* answer would collect and summarize the more useful ones.

Comment: @ThomasDickey It's easy to find a duplicate answer, the hard part is finding a duplicate question -- I wanted to avoid marking questions about "unexpected end of file" as duplicates of "bad interpretter" as this would seem confusing. I don't disagree though, and I'll support any question and/or answer you find/edit/post. I just want a canonical question to dedupe with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TL;DR: Your script has Windows style CRLF line endings, aka `\r\n`.

Convert to Unix style `\n` by deleting the carriage returns.

---

#### How do I check if my script has carriage returns?

They're detectable as `^M` in the output of `cat -v yourscript`:

```
$ cat -v myscript
if true^M
then^M
  true^M
...
```

#### How do I remove them?

Set your editor to save the file with Unix line endings, aka "line terminators" or "end-of-line characters", and resave it.

You can also remove them from a command line with `dos2unix yourscript` or `cat yourscript | tr -d '\r' > fixedscript`.

#### Why do carriage returns cause syntax errors?

The carriage return character is just another character to bash. `then` is not the same as `then\r`, so bash doesn't recognize it as a keyword and assumes it's a command. It then keeps looking for a `then` and fails

If there happens to be a trailing space after `then`, you get a similar problem for `fi`.