# Bash error: Syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have this script that almost the same as another but while the other script works fine this one does not want to work.

It has to replace the `;` with `,` and to join some csv files located in a path starting with some name, excluding the first line of all the files except the first one.

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /Desktop/AnotherFolder/newname.csv ] 
then
    rm /Desktop/AnotherFolder/newname.csv
fi

i=0
for f in /Desktop/NewFolder/somename*.csv
do 
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]
    then 
        #Converto il carattere | in virgola
        sed 's/;/,/g' $f > /Desktop/AnotherFolder/newname.csv
        let "i += 1"
    else
        tail -n+2 $f | sed 's/;/,/g' $f >> /Desktop/AnotherFolder/newname.csv
    fi
done
```

Error:

`line 18 Bash error: syntax Syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right script? Your error said Line 28, but this script only has 17 lines.

Comment: Always, always, always test that your cut-down example actually reproduces the bug at hand. And run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ for good measure.

Comment: I deleted some comment lines and now the error is on line 18.

Comment: @Mario Can you see if it's [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere/31886145#31886145)?

Comment: Heh. I'd actually put money on that being it.

Comment: Thank you all you guys! It was the cat problem. I had some ^M in my script.