# Why does this infinite while loop produce "unexpected end of file" with bash?

Tags: bash, while-loop, syntax-error, infinite-loop

Could anyone offer some insight as to why this would give me an unexpected end of file error at line 5?
I tried following a guide with making an infinite while loop but I couldn't figure out why mine was any different.
Here's all the code:

```
while :
do
    screen -S pvp java -Xms8G -jar spigots.jar nogui
done
```

(I also tried with true instead of the :)

If anyone can see why it would throw that error, please tell me :)
If you need any more information let me know

Comment: you must turn on some switch like `set -e` or something else. try to add `set -x` at the top of your script and keep the stderr and see what happened.

Comment: Your script is of 4 lines which you showed and error is coming on 5th line, so do you have only this code snippet or any other code is also there, please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This is all the code, edited for clarification on that.

Comment: How are you running this script and what's the error message?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Added set -x to the top, gave 'invalid option 1: set -'. Without the - it didn't give an other than the original on line 6.

Comment: is that even bash? type `help set` in any session. what does it say?

Comment: @melpomene running it on a linux vps with ./start.sh and the error message is ' line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file'

Comment: ... and you don't have a `#!` line in your script?

Comment: @melpomene No, first time doing this so I have little knowledge of things.

Comment: Loop is correct but the screen command

Comment: I'm pretty sure @thatotherguy is right that the script has DOS/Windows line endings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere)). That "invalid option" error message where the close quote is at the beginning of the line is a dead giveaway.