# syntax error: unexpected end of file in if statement bash file

Tags: bash

Source code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Parametro is $1"
if [ $1 -gt 9 ]
    then
    echo "entre al if";
fi
echo"Fin del script";
```

My bash file has execute permission:

```
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 mzadmin mzadmin 108 Feb 15 13:07 test.sh
```

I run my bash file like:

```
bash test.sh 9
```

And the output is:

```
Parametro is 9
test.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

Comment: The posted script doesn't *have* a line 8.

Comment: @chepner Interestingly, the error does get reported on line 8. This happens both with and without a terminating linefeed on line 7.

Comment: This is probably due to carriage returns. See [Why is a shell script giving syntax errors when the same code works elsewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

You need a space after `echo` command : `echo"Fin del script";`

So :

```
echo "Fin del script"
```

Next time, before asking human help, please pass your script online on http://www.shellcheck.net/ (even if this particular error is not detected, because the shell think `echo"Fin del script";` is a unknown command...)

### Edit

If you don't have output it's because you use in your test `-gt` (*is greater*) but instead you need `-ge` is *greater or equal*.

Better use [*bash arithmetic*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) like this, it's more readable and less error prone :

```
if ((arg >= 9)); then
```

Comment: thaks for your answer, I checked my code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and I found other mistake:                                                                                                         Line 3:
if [ $1 -gt 9 ]
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.                     I solved this new mistake and the output is the same. ;(

Comment: Check my edited post

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a newline at the end of your script, because sometimes things don't work properly if they can't find a newline character. See [Why should text files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)

Comment: thaks, but I solved this mistake and the output is the same ;( ;(.                                   #!/bin/bash
echo "Parametro is $1"
if [ "$1" -gt 9 ]
 then
 echo "entre al if"
fi
echo "Fin del script"

                                                                                                                                         I put two newline at the end. :(

Comment: thanks guys. I solved my error. the source code is ok, but I am working in windows and after put my file.sh to the Server linux and something is wrong  with this case. If I create my file.sh in the server using "vi filename.sh" and I type the same source code, save and after execute "bash filename.sh" everything works fine.