# Why do I get "syntax error near unexpected token `done'" in my Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    ip="$line"
    torify ./PRET/pret.py $ip pjl -q -i ./commands.txt
done < "./potential_bros.txt"
```

Why do I get this error?

commands.txt=

```
print ./message.pdf
display Completed
quit
```

potential_bros.txt = my ip

PRET = https://github.com/RUB-NDS/PRET

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I can't reproduce it neither.  I added an answer to prove it to you .  Aaalol, please be sure to include exact examples in your questions; if we don't have exact code that causes the error, we can't help.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Why is a shell script giving syntax errors when the same code works elsewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I fail to reproduce this error.  Example that works:

```
$ cat t.sh
while read -r line ; do
  echo $line
done  < t.txt

$ cat t.txt
item1
item2
item3

$ ./t.sh
item1
item2
item3
```

Comment: @AaalolGimenezGimenez That edit doesn't make anything clear to me. Would you mind adding a few words explaining it?

Comment: the code tries to enter a py file that enters the printer with the ip of the printer that is in potential bros.txt and enters command.txt to print message.pdf

Comment: @AaalolGimenezGimenez, it doesn't matter what is in `commands.txt`, a file path argument passed to `torify`.    The reason your script doesn't work is not the syntax you're using; that's my point.