# issue in shell script not working in redhat working fine in ubuntu

Tags: redhat

```
#!/bin/sh

# Define your function here
Hello () {
   echo "Hello World"
}

Hello
```

above script is running fine in `ubuntu` but showing following error
on `redhat machine`

```
"syntax error near unexpected token ' { "
```

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895946/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-bash

Comment: Which shell is `/bin/sh` on your redhat really?

Comment: I have run following command cat /etc/shells
and output is   
 /bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/bin/dash
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh

Comment: thanks alpert, it was encoding issue. It got resolved now, actually i have created sh file in ubuntu and executing on Redhat :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's Shell is bash but its not shells error becuase i am using ubuntu and your program give me o/p like this

> sh hello.sh 
>   Hello World